# "the same" and "that particular one"

Tags: adjectives, ambiguity

Consider

> I'm driving the same car.

It sounds like me and someone else share one and the same car. But I could mean that my car is just another copy of the same model of the car. How do I express that?

Comment: The thing is, it doesn't really sound like you share the same copy of a car if the context is known.  When I get dropped off by a friend, I can say "that's me" to point out my house.  At a restaurant, I can say "I'll have what she's having" and it doesn't mean that I intend to share the plate of food.  On an airplane, I can say "you seem to be in my seat", without the person thinking I own the seat.  If the person you are talking to is totally thick, a wiseass, or a robot, then your best bet is saying "my car is just another copy of the same model of the car".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does English have frequently used ordinary words that distinguish between equality and equivalence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28990/does-english-have-frequently-used-ordinary-words-that-distinguish-between-equalit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were to say, in casual conversation,

> Tom and I drive the same car.

most Americans would assume you meant the same make and model. You wouldn't have to specify that you did not mean a single shared vehicle. In fact, if you *did* mean a single vehicle you would probably have to add information to the above example, or phrase the sentence differently, as in

> Tom and I share a car.

Comment: Ditto this comment.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm driving a car just like his!"

Comment: Thanks, good idea! Though this appears to be ambiguous again. People could think i meant "with the same bad brakes/form/speed etc". In germany, for example, we can say "Ich fahre das gleiche Auto", which is entirely unambiguous.

Comment: @Johannes: which is why I didn't use "exactly like his". ;)

Comment: M. oh i see!

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce ambiguity by saying

> I'm driving the same model of car.

or

> I drive the same model.

Answer (score 1):

Just to pour petrol on the flames here, consider [David Deutsch's](http://mag.digitalpc.co.uk/Olive/ODE/physicsworld/LandingPage/LandingPage.aspx?href=UEhZU1dvZGUvMjAxMS8wNS8wMQ..&pageno=MzY.&entity=QXIwMzYwMA..&view=ZW50aXR5)  use of the word [fungible](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/fungible.html) in his latest book [The Beginning of Infinity](http://beginningofinfinity.com/).

So far as I can make out, if you and Deutsch had **fungible** cars, there would actually be two of them. But they would be identical in every respect, including every consituent atom being the same, *and* the two cars being in exactly the same location within the space-time continuum.

After reading Deutsch I'm no longer sure what **the same** means at all, let alone how one could distinguish it from **very similar** using just the English language!

Comment: Fixed yer link.

Comment: @MT_Head: Oh lummie! Many thanks. Having only read this question last week, and Deutsch's book last night, I just couldn't resist trying to promote this exotic concept of fungibility.

Answer (score 1):

`Identical` works well here:

> I'm driving an identical car.
>
> Tom and I drive identical cars.