# We have the same car vs we have the same cars

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

If me and someone have the same car.  It is correct to say: we have the same car or we have the same cars.

Comment: [Question has already been answered.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127172/the-same-and-same) Please use the search function before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the first is correct. The second one would be used if each of you had more than one car.